# How do advanced computer users plan for the worst case scenario with their password managers?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-recovery

I use KeePassXC as my password manager of choice and have my database synced between my computers and phone as I'm not a fan of having all of my credentials accessible on the web (no matter how secure/trustworthy the provider is).

If I lose access to my devices (maybe a burglary or my house burns down) then I'd lose access to all of my online accounts.

I wouldn't be able to:

- Log into Google (despite that being the only password I know of by heart) because of their 2FA (two-factor authentication).
- Order a replacement SIM card because my online account's password with my network is also randomly generated.
- Use my phone number as an alternative choice for Google's 2FA.
- Recover my backed up database from Google Drive.

How do advanced computer users plan for the worst case scenario?  Do they leave themselves a backdoor of some kind?

Comment: On the note about Google 2FA: If I remember correctly, Google will give you some printable backup keys, which can be used as a last resort if all your other options aren't working.

Comment: Switched your [use of “nerds” to “people” in your original post](https://superuser.com/revisions/1645541/1) because you are asking a valid question that is potentially ruined by being obnoxious.

Comment: Sorry, Giacomo1968, I'm a nerd so I didn't see it as offensive.

Comment: jitter: do people store their backup codes in a deposit box or something? if their house burns down then they might lose their codes.

Comment: Nerd is kind of subjective. Some people find it offensive, other people don't mind. It's best to just avoid using such wording on StackExchange (and most other forums for that matter)

Comment: @charlie You can print more last time I checked. You can just throw them in a fireproof box or whatever, or just keep them in your wallet, etc. The codes are like 5 or 6 digits if I remember correctly. The chance that your passwords are compromised and your house burns down is extremely rare, so I don't think you'll really have to worry about that happening. Just make sure those backup codes are safe and you should be fine.

Comment: "People" isn't the right word either because I want answers from the technically minded.

Comment: Also, as a general tip: instead of just saying "jitter", you can tag people with an @ followed by their username, which can help others know who your comment is directed towards.

Comment: @charlie You're on a technology forum; everyone here is technically minded.

Comment: @jitter lol that's why I chose this forum.  Storing such backup codes should be an answer in itself.

Comment: Store your keypass encrypted database in the cloud.

Comment: ‘some woke user got offended by the word "nerd" and changed the original meaning of the question.’ Nope. I wasn’t offended. I simply thought you were obnoxious. Your edit to “advanced computer users” is obnoxious as well. You don’t need to be a “nerd” or an “advanced computer user” to deal with stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burglary often takes place when people are not home. In that case, I normally have one computer with me. Key passwords are in a separate place.

Fire: We may, may not be home. If home, chances are fire can be put under control not damaging all the computers.

So a worst case were all computers are destroyed or lost is quite unlikely.

When we are away for any length of time (vacation / trip) I always have my laptop, phone and wallet.

So risks can be mitigated to a great extent.

Comment: How about placing a piece of paper with a single backup code beneath my car's carpet for added peace of mind?  I know it's very, very unlikely to lose everything, but it is everything that can be lost.

Comment: I have most important passwords (Bank, Credit Card) in my head and I use these passwords frequently so I do not forget. Your idea is reasonable.

Comment: Oh, I could send a small transfer from one bank account to another with a backup code as a transfer reference (I like your cryptic hint).

Answer (score 0):

All eggs in one basket is always a poor strategy.
You have duplication, which is good, but they're all in one place.

You need a copy off-site.
Whether you do that with a simple CD kept at your mum's, or a more complex online backup, it has to be somewhere that burning down the house won't destroy.
I get that you don't want this online, but a well-encrypted zip file on a non-related server is going to be pretty secure. if the whole lot burns you will, of course, need one device that can get you a) the app again & b) the database it needs to function. That path needs to be simple, if obscure.

The rest of your strategy sounds fine, you just need at least one more location.